# Can I upgrade to a 11 speed freehub or do I need to change everything?

Tags: shimano, speed

I have a set of Shimano WH-RS10 hubs on my bike. Can I upgrade to a 11 speed freehub or do I need to change everything?  If not what would I need to upgrade to 11 speed wheel?

Comment: Gidday again - thank you for taking my suggestion.  Now we wait for an answer from someone who can help.  Once a couple days have passed, you can accept the best answer by clicking the green tick/check box.

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer:

Given that the WH-RS10 isn't a fancy wheel, if you can't just get a 11 speed freehub body, you're going to be best off economically by just replacing the whole rear wheel if you want to go 11 speed. I suspect there isn't a replacement to 11 speed, but you can ask your bike shop or someone else may answer there is.

Interestingly, Zinn has figured out that you can [file the feet of the splines down on an existing Shimano 10 speed freehub](http://velonews.competitor.com/2013/10/bikes-and-tech/how-to-convert-a-10-speed-29er-wheel-to-a-cross-disc-hoop-and-align-rotors_306588) to fit a 11 speed cassette on it, since the difference is only a few mm. But this is at your own risk, and may or may not work.

Comment: That makes me wonder if I just change the freehub then it would fit.

Comment: Rebuilding a wheel is a decent amount of work. If you were to have a new hub put in and the wheel rebuilt with new spokes, you'd probably be paying as much as getting the rear wheel new in the first place, except the resulting wheel might be worse depending on how well the wheel was built. Plus, you can sell the existing wheel if you want to.

Comment: I'm thinking about changing just the freehub, not the whole hub assembly. I agree with you about changing the whole hub assembly, it would just cost more.